# UIPopover and UITableView data exchange

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uipopover

I have a UITableView in a UINavigationController. On the navigation bar I have a button called add. When this button is pressed it presents a UIPopoverController, where user can input data to be added as a new row/cell in the UITableView. My issue is how can I add a new cell to the UITableView from the UIPopover? Do I pass in the array data to the UIPopOver root controller?

Comment: I guess it would depend on your table view's data source. If you have worked with modal views on the iPhone to do the same thing, it should be a similar pattern with the popover on the iPad.

Comment: yea, it would be the same with modal view.. question is how? and when you say it depends on the data source, what does that mean? I want to be able to do insertRowsAtIndexPath from the popover.. that's the main goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solutions to this that I'm aware of.  One would be to send a notification from the popover to the root controller and apply the necessary code to update the tableView in the `handleNotification` method.

The other, one that I personally use, is to set up a delegate protocol for the popover.  You'll have to set it up something like this:

```
@protocol PopoverDelegate
- (void)addNewCell;  // you can add any information you need to pass onto this if necessary such as addNewCellWithName:(NSString *)name, etc.
@end

@interface MyPopoverViewController..... {
    id <PopoverDelegate> delegate;
    // the rest of your interface code;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
// any other methods or properties;
@end
```

Then in your root view controller header file, you need to add the delegate

```
@interface RootViewController .... <PopoverDelegate> {
```

Then in your root view controller implementation file, assign the popover delegate when you instantiate it.  For example:

```
MyPopoverViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
vc.delegate = self;  // this is where you set your protocol delegate
myPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
myPopover.delegate = self;
[vc release];
```

Finally, you'll add your protocol method somewhere in the code

```
- (void)addNewCell {
    // do what you want with the tableView from here
}
```

Sorry that's a bit long.  I just wanted to make sure I was thorough.  Hope it helps